# loop through array with index in vba and get element at specific index

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am right now trying something like this

```
Dim myAddress() As String
myAddress= Split("4th Street NW Washington, DC")

For intI = 1 To UBound(myAddress)
     `how can i access myAddress[intI+1] from here?
Next intI
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim myAddress() As String
myAddress= Split("4th Street NW Washington, DC")

For intI = 1 To UBound(myAddress)
    Console.WriteLine(myAddress(intI))
Next intI
```

Comment: thanks that does work the problem within that loop how would i access the +1 or next element

Comment: VBA defaults to 0 as the index of the first array element.

Comment: awesome! so I can do myAddress(intI+1)? is there a way to check if it's a valid index?

Comment: Valid index values are `>= LBound(myAddress) And <= UBound(myAddress)`